# Weyl group stabilizer of semisimple element in adjoint group

Tags: reference-request, lie-groups, weyl-group

Let $G$ be semisimple group over $\mathbb{C}$ of adjoint type. Let $T$ be a maximal torus, $s\in T$ semisimple element. Let $W$ be a Weyl group and $W(s)$ be a stabilizer of $s$ in $W$. I am interested in question: weather $W(s)$ is generated by reflections?

Let $\tilde{G}$ denotes simply connected cover of $G$, $\tilde{s}\in \tilde{G}$ denotes some lift of $s$. Then the centralizer $C_{\tilde G} (\tilde s)$ is connected and reductive. The $W(\tilde s)$ is Weyl group of $C_{\tilde G} (\tilde s)$ and generated by reflections.

The group $W(s)$ is genereted by $W(\tilde s)$ and also some elements in $W$ which permutes different lifts of $s$ to $\tilde{G}$. For $C_{\tilde G} (\tilde s)$ these elements are  'diagram automorphisms'

**Question.** *It there any classification of $s$ such that $W(s)$ differs from $W(\tilde s)$?* 
This looks more or less straightforward (at least for classical types) but I couldn't find reference.

Another question is about affine analogue. Let $T^a=T\times \mathbb{C}^*$ be a torus of affine group, there is an action of affine Weyl group $W^a$ on $\hat{T}$. For any $s^a \in T^a$ let $W^a(s^a)$ denotes its stabilizer in $W^a$.

**Question.** *Is there any reference about $W^a(s^a)$? I am interested about the same question: weather $W^a(s^a)$ is generated by reflections?*

Recall the $W^a=W \ltimes Q^\vee$, where $Q^\vee$ is a coroot lattice. Since $Q^\vee$ acts on $T^a$ freely the natural map $W^a(s^a) \rightarrow W$ is injective, so the this question should be very close to the non affine case. But I could not find a reference.

Comment: Let $G=PGL_3$ and let $s$ be the diagonal matrix with eigenvalues given by 3 distinct roots of 1 of order 3. Then $W(s)={\mathbb Z}/3$, so it is not generated by reflections.

Comment: Yes, of course. My question is there any classification of such $s$.

For such $s$ it is necessary that $W(s)$ is larger then $W(\tilde{s})$. And for example for $PGL_N$ this means that multiset of eigenvalues of $\tilde{s}$ is invariant under multiplication on some $N$-th root of unity.
So I am asking for similar classification for other types.